# how to find out which dialog was sent the store request touch ui or classic ui?

Tags: aem

Is it possible to find out whether the values stored in CRX are from touchui dialog or from classic ui dialog. 
I am creating a checkbox for both UIs. When touchui dialog saves value in CRX it saves on but when classic ui saves value, it saves true. which makes it difficult to use value after reading( touch ui does not recognize true and classic ui does not take on).
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Not really. Both mechanisms simply make a POST request to the appropiate resource to create/update it. You could add a hidden field to identify it, but I would recommend against this.

Instead, you should properly configure your dialogs so both versions store your properties in the same way.

In the granite version of the checkbox you can configure the value that will be set in the checkbox with the "value" property. ([check the docs for more info](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/checkbox/index.html))